# linux command top: saving configuration

Tags: linux, configuration, top

I am learning command top, know how to change color and  columns mod, switch from one mode to another. After closing top's window and running again, all comes to default configuration - 4 default modes of columns and colors . Is there any way to save changes befor closing top's window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you have your configuration set the way you want, type `W` (that is a capital W) and your configuration will be saved.

From the `top` manpage:

> ´W´ :Write_the_Configuration_File
>
> This  will  save all of your options and toggles plus the current display mode and delay time.  By issuing this command just before quitting top, you will be able restart later in exactly that same state.